# How do i make an info window in google maps bigger?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Im trying to make the window bigger so that i can fit a news feed from twitter into it. I messed around with some inline styles trying to make the width and height bigger, couldnt get it to work, heres the code iv done so far.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var lnl = new google.maps.LatLng(33.8564199,-117.3610477);
  var opt = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: lnl
  }
  var poop = '<div id="poop2" >' + '<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/GreekTheatreLA" data-widget-id="448463912984256512">Tweets by @GreekTheatreLA</a>' + '</div>';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-props'), opt);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<p id="hook"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/GreekTheatreLA" data-widget-id="448463912984256512">Tweets by @GreekTheatreLA</a></p>'
});

  var griff = new google.maps.LatLng(34.1183438,-118.3003646);
  var griff_mark = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: griff,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: "Griffith Observatory"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(griff_mark, 'click', function(){
    infowindow.open(map, griff_mark);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add maxWidth to your code in infowindow as shown below.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content:'<p id="hook" style="height:200px; width: 800px;"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/GreekTheatreLA" data-widget-id="448463912984256512">Tweets by @GreekTheatreLA</a></p>',
maxWidth: 200
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i had tried that earlier myself, but that just replaces the whole map, i get the news feed but evreything else is gone, any ideas to why that could happen?

Comment: Try this    <p id="hook" style="height:200px; width: 800px;">

Comment: Nice...I'll edit the answer, can u pls accept my answer.